# Filtering out irrelevant data from a broad crawl

Tags: python, web-scraping, nlp, scrapy, cosine-similarity

I am using scrapy to crawl data from Google. I would like to get the text from the first 20 hits, and then filter out any "outlier" from the scraped text. Basically, I would like to identify how similar the results are by first transforming the text into a vector, comparing this similarity using some metric, and then drop any results that gets a similarity "score" lower than some pre-defined threshold, as this would mean that that specific text is not related to the rest of the results.

I'm thinking of using something like [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) but from what I see, this works best when comparing one text block to another. However, what I need is to compare one text block with the rest of the scraped text.

Suppose, for example, that my crawl returned these results:

```
[1] XYZ is a fintech startup accelerating access to credit in emerging markets. We enable consumers to build their credit history while making easier payments .
[2] Denver-based XYZ Co., a buy now, pay later startup focused on emerging markets, announced today it has raised $2.2 million..
[3] XYZ builds an alternative credit score and app that provides store credit financing to buy essentials like food and medicine.
[4] Want to know more about XYZ? Terms of UsePrivacy Policy. All rights reserved. Copyright © 2022
```

I would like to be able to calculate a similarity score that will help me identify result number 4 as an "outlier" or as irrelevant and thus drop it from further processing.

What would be the best way to implement this?

EDIT: Added examples.

Comment: Hello! This sounds like a fun problem. I would try lots of things. I would try k-means clustering to group similar results. I would try principal component analysis as well.

Comment: Note that stackoverflow questions work better if you provide a small example than if you ask for recommendations in the abstract. Could you include a set of 10 small paragraphs, and explain what kind of filtering you would like with this set of 10 paragraphs?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.